# SPARK: Identical stages generated despite caching

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am wondering how could I have two exactly identical stages despite that I cache my data before each action in Spark.
Can you look at the below screenshot it looks strange to me. Does this mean that I am executing the tasks in the stages twice?

Unfortunately it's quite hard to give code example, but I will try to explain what I do.

1. Read data from CSV
2. Do some transformations on specific columns.
3. Apply schema -> `spark.Session.createDataFrame(df.rdd,schema)`
4. Create 7 new dataframes by using different filters on the DF created at point 3)
5. Take two of the dataframes from point 4 and pass them to another method for comparison reasons.

I persist after point 2) and after point 4) only the two dataframes that will be compared. And unpersist after comparison. The comparison is long and complex process.

[image]

Comment: I find these DAGs sometime hard to interprete. I

Comment: Run some action after the persist like df.count or df.take(n) and see if the stages changes.

Comment: Unfortunately no change. The DAG looks the same.

Comment: Any updates on the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can see if a DataFrame was cached in your physical plan using explain operator (where InMemoryRelation entities reflect cached datasets with their storage level):

```
== Physical Plan ==
*Project [id#0L, id#0L AS newId#16L]
+- InMemoryTableScan [id#0L]
      +- InMemoryRelation [id#0L], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
            +- *Range (0, 1, step=1, splits=Some(8))
```

After you cache (or persist) your DataFrame the first query may get slower, but it is going to pay off for the following queries.

You can check whether a Dataset was cached or not using the following code:

```
scala> :type q2
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]

val cache = spark.sharedState.cacheManager
scala> cache.lookupCachedData(q2.queryExecution.logical).isDefined
res0: Boolean = false
```

There's one surprise with caching in Spark SQL. Caching is lazy and that's why you pay the extra price to have rows cached the very first action, but that only happens with DataFrame API. In SQL, caching is eager which makes a huge difference in query performance as you don't have you call an action to trigger caching.